# How to redirect to specific page after login into site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, authentication, login

I have specific requirement for my SharePoint 2013 publishing sub sites.
There is no direct URL for accessing site content in SharePoint 
we need custom URL to redirect site content page after login

For example:

When user type 
http://SharePoint/sites/subsite/login

It should open login popup (native SharePoint login popup) and after entering valid credentials it should redirect to

http://SharePoint/sites/subsite/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx

Thanks